# How to download only the beginning of a large file with go http.Client (and app engine urlfetch)

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm trying to download only the first 1kb of large files using `http.Client` in go, but it seems like `response.Body` is always fully buffered. Is there a control over how much to buffer?

If so, how can this be used with app engine urlfetch service?

The following works fine with app engine urlfetch in python, and I'm trying to port this to go:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
req = Request(url)
urlopen(req).read(1024) # Read the first 1kb.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Setting "Range" Request Header attribute to "bytes=0-1023" should work.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://example.com", nil)
    req.Header.Add("Range", "bytes=0-1023")
    fmt.Println(req)
    var client http.Client
    resp, _ := client.Do(req)
    fmt.Println(resp)
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Println(len(body))
}
```

Same thing should work for http.Client provieded in app engine.

Comment: While this works fine (also with app engine), not all http servers accept range. Is there a client-only method which is independent of server range support?

Comment: You can try implementing your own [RoundTripper](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#RoundTripper) and using it as Transport in Client.

Comment: The `RoundTripper` is implemented internally in app engine urlfetch, it does not seem to be extendable. While this is not a general solution, in my case, the servers support accepting range.

Comment: as @ali pointed out, you must first make sure the server accepts partial downloads by looking at the response in the header for `Accept-Ranges`. if you want to do the check before downloading the file, you can send a `HEAD` request to the same endpoint, and check for this header (and eventually that the server responds a 206 status indicating partial content).

Answer (score 3):

There is also io.LimitReader() in io pkg, which can make limited reader

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    var client http.Client
    responce, _:=client.Get("http://example.com")
    body:=responce.Body
    chunk:=io.LimitReader(body, 1024)
    stuff, _:=ioutil.ReadAll(chunk)
    //Do what you want with stuff
}
```

Comment: This only _reads_ the first 1kb, but downloads the whole file. `client.Get("http://example.com")` has fully buffered `response.Body`, even before using any readers on it.

Comment: @ali No it doesn't download the whole file. At least on my machine.

Comment: Have you tried it with app engine? Unfortunately [appengine/urlfetch](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/urlfetch/) buffers it all once `client.Get()` is called. This might be due to `urlfetch.Transport`.